# Too many HashedWheelTimer instances

Tags: clojure, websocket, netty

I'm using [http.async.client](https://github.com/cch1/http.async.client) 1.1.0 in Clojure to create websocket client. My code is almost exact [example websocket client](https://github.com/cch1/http.async.client#websocket-client), with added few lines of logic which:

- reconnect the connection on disconnect, with increasing wait times starting with few seconds and ending with about a minute
- code that synchronously closes the previous websocket if it exists and is open

My problem is that after running this for a few days to a week I get this error message printed on console. It is not output by my logging or anything in my application, and while at first I thought it was linked to reconnects, I also get it when there are no reconnects few hours before or after.

```
Jul 24, 2016 6:48:18 AM org.jboss.netty.util.internal.SharedResourceMisuseDetector
WARNING: You are creating too many HashedWheelTimer instances. HashedWheelTimer is a shared resource that must be reused across the application, so that only a few instances are created.
```

This seems to be triggered by Netty's [SharedResourceMisuseDetector](http://netty.io/3.9/xref/org/jboss/netty/util/internal/SharedResourceMisuseDetector.html) used by the [Asynchronous Http Client for Java](http://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client). This happens when there are more than 256 instances of HashedWheelTimer. I'm trying to understand what would create that many instances of HashedWheelTimer when everything points that there should be only one HashedWheelTimer. This looks like something doesn't cleanup after itself properly. Does anyone have any idea what exactly creates HashedWheelTimers and how to prevent it?

Comment: the reconnect logic would be the first place to look, for me. It would make the question much easier to answer if you could paste them into the question. There could be something like the loop/recur having a ( in the wrong place so it includes the connection creation. or perhaps the reconnect is holding onto a reference to the old connection. I can only guess without seeing some code. And does the sample code also have this problem without any of your changes (except change the infinite spin loop at the bottom to something more reasonable)

Comment: Reconnect code is pretty simple and works like this: on disconnect, wait a bit in a future and call the connect function. Connect function checks the atom in which previous client is stored, and if it exists closes it and then opens a new connection. The only client related code is: (client/close @current-client) and then: (client/websocket (client/create-client) url :open  on-open :close on-close :error on-error :text  handle-message). The sample code and my code is the same, minus the spin function, and plus some logic to process data through that comes through the wire (doesn't use Netty).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the culprit.

What I was doing for each reconnect is:

```
(client/websocket (client/create-client) url ...)
```

...or in other words creating new client every time. It seems that every new client instantiates its own HashedWheelTimer. So now I instance only one client and reuse it, and that seems to have fixed the problem.